# PythonTypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def ising_optimize(matrix) :
    """
    Return the minimum value of E(x) with the matrix given as the input
    parameter.
    The matrix is provided either as a Python list-of-lists or as a 
    string which is the path to a CSV file.
    """

    m = int(input('number of rows = '))
    n = int(input('number of columns = '))
    mat_x = []

    for i in range(0,m):                  # initialize the number of rows
        mat_x += [0]

    for i in range (0,m):                # initialize the matrix
        mat_x[i] = [0]*n
    for i in range (0,m):
        for j in range (0,n):
            print ('entry for row: ',i+1,'with column: ',j+1)
            mat_x[i][j] = float(input())
    print (mat_x)
    W = [[0,1], [1, 0]]
    flat_matrix_list = ([item for sublist in matrix for item in sublist])
    print(flat_matrix_list)
    sum = []
    for w in range(len(flat_matrix_list)):
        t=0
        for x in range(len(mat_x)):
            e = (w[0]*x[0]+w[1]*x[1]+w[2]*x[2]+w[3]*x[3])
            t = -(e/2)
            sum.append(t)
    print(t)
    return 0
```

Comment: What do you *want* `w` and `x` to be in your final for loop, where you are calculating `e = ...` because they aren't what you think they are. I think `w` and `x` are indexes into some array you have but I'm not sure what your function is even supposed to be doing

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this piece of code:

```
for w in range(len(flat_matrix_list)):
        t=0
        for x in range(len(mat_x)):
            e = (w[0]*x[0]+w[1]*x[1]+w[2]*x[2]+w[3]*x[3])
            t = -(e/2)
            sum.append(t)
```

Here, `w` and `x` are **integers**.

When you write `w in range(len(flat_matrix_list))`, then the value of w will be 0 in the first iteration, then 1, 2, ..., up until the length of the array. And you cannot use subscripts (e.g. `w[0]`) on an integer, this makes no sense.

Even the elements of the `flat_matrix_list` array themselves are integers, so using `for w in flat_matrix_list` as per @JohnGordon's answer will not help.

**Help us help you**, what exactly are you trying to do with this piece of code?

Answer (score -1):

```
for w in range(len(flat_matrix_list)):
    t=0
    for x in range(len(mat_x)):
        e = (w[0]*x[0]+w[1]*x[1]+w[2]*x[2]+w[3]*x[3])
```

`w` and `x` are single integers.  It makes no sense to say `w[0]` or `x[2]`.

Did you mean to say `for w in flat_matrix_list:` instead?  That might make sense, as then `w` would be each *item* in that list, and you could sub-index into it.

Comment: Right, there's where the problem is. However, even if the OP meant to do `for w in flat_matrix_list:`, `w` would still be an integer (the array is a flat array of integers)